# Can guava be used for reflection on classes that are loaded by name?

Tags: java, reflection, guava

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418621/java-reflection-getting-correct-type-of-parameterized-generic-superclass-method/45419534#45419534) I was referred to guava as a solution for reflection on generics, and it looks awesome except that I get errors trying to use this on classes loaded by name:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("net.redpoint.scratch.Derived");
TypeToken tt = new TypeToken(clazz) {};
```

This results in the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken isn't parameterized

Is there some way to use TypeToken without having the class at compile-time?  Note that I also do not have source to these classes.

Comment: Have you tried using `TypeToken.of(clazz)`?

Comment: Thanks!  If you submit this as an answer, I will mark it.  It may seem trivial, but I was having trouble connecting the dots.

Comment: @Wheezil you can also self-answer, so that the question is at least marked "answered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [M Prokhorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7470253/m-prokhorov) says, "use TypeToken.of(class)"